# Get Index ID by Click on Link Button

Tags: vb.net, gridview

How to get the index id of particular click on link button to the next page in grid view?

My code: Here I use hidden field in it

```
If e.CommandName = "facilitywell" Then
    Dim routeId As String = CType(gView.Rows(indexNum).FindControl("lblpid"), Label).Text
    'CType(gView.Rows(indexNum).FindControl("hfRouteid"), HiddenField).Value
    Response.Redirect("~/frmRouteFacilityWell.aspx?routeId=" + routeId
```

Source Page Code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbRouteFacilityWell" runat="server" CommandName="facilitywell">FacilityWell</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 lblpid= gView.SelectedRows(0).Cells("lblpid").Value
```

Try This